# ProgressBar windows form c#

Tags: c#

Having a large sincronous code that use BinaryFormatter to serialize several tables how can i update progressbar ?

the code that perform serialization is :

```
 private void Serialize()
    {
        try
        {

            int numberTableProcessed = 0;

            txtBoxProcessing.Text += "Start ..." + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine;


            AGENTS agenti = new AGENTS();
            agenti.SelectAndSerializeAgenti(openedConn);
            string pathAgenti = @"C:\...AGENTS.bin";
            if (File.Exists(pathAgenti))
            {
                long size = new FileInfo(pathAgenti).Length;
                 txtBoxProcessing.Text += "Processed AGENTI - " + string.Format("byte: {0:n}", size) + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            numberTableProcessed++;
            UpdateProgressBar(numberTableProcessed);

            PRODUCT anaart = new PRODUCT();
            anaart.SelectAndSerializeAnaart(openedConn);
            string pathAnaart = @"C:\...PRODUCT.bin";
            if (File.Exists(pathAnaart))
            {
                long size = new FileInfo(pathAnaart).Length;
                 txtBoxProcessing.Text += "Processed PRODUCT - " + string.Format("byte: {0:n}", size) + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            numberTableProcessed++;
            UpdateProgressBar(numberTableProcessed);
            ...
```

}

the code that update the progressbar

```
private void UpdateProgressBar(int numberTableProcessed)
    {
        int numberTotalTables = 22;
        progressBar1.Value = (numberTableProcessed / numberTotalTables) * 100;
    }
```

Using the method UpdateProgressBar i not see progress...it becomes full green at the end because the code is running sincronous (i think)

how can update progressbar?

I try this based on Lucifer suggest

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    }

    public void PerformSerialize()
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Serialize();
    }

    private void btnSerializza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Serialize();
        PerformSerialize();
    }
    public void UpdateProgressBar(int numberTableProcessed)
    {
        if (this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { UpdateProgressBar(numberTableProcessed); });
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                int numberTotalTables = 22;
                progressBar1.Value = (numberTableProcessed / numberTotalTables) * 100;
                progressBar1.Increment(numberTotalTables);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The most appropriate option would probably be to execute that `Serialize` method on a secondary thread and make `UpdateProgressBar` thread-safe, i.e. make it marshal a call to the UI thread.  You might also be able to simply call `Refresh` on the `ProgressBar` after setting its `Value` but I'm not sure that that will work for that control in particular.

Comment: Try to change `(numberTableProcessed * 100) / numberTotalTables` You always get zero until it is "full"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You need to perform the serialization task into another thread.

Explanation:

1. Here you will first create a `backgroundworker` (global or local your choice).
2. you will call `PerformSerialize()` from the place where you are calling `serialize()` as of now which will call `bgworker_dowork` which will initiate a separate thread.
3. you need to change structure of your UpgradeProgress method structure as I have shown to make it `thread safe`[(Read this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-do-i-update-the-gui-from-another-thread).

here is sample code which may help you

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

public void UpdateProgressBar(int numberTableProcessed)
{
  if (this.IsHandleCreated)
  {
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{UpdateProgressBar(numberTableProcessed);});
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        int numberTotalTables = 22;
        progressBar1.Value = (numberTableProcessed * 100) / numberTotalTables
    }
}

this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
```

call this method from where you call serialize.

```
public void PerformSerialize()
{
  backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     //call Serialize() method
}
```

[image: working]

Comment: i try your code and i place in the button form PerformSerialize but nothig happen.

Comment: @MeJonata please edit question & show what you tried in detail, did you place the serialize method in background worker's code?

Comment: In my Button click (Serialize) i debug and when call PerformSerialize() nothig happen ...it return the form

Comment: you need to but breakpoint in backgroundWorker1_DoWork() as such it is other thread

Comment: ok in debug i get exception:Operazione cross-thread non valida: è stato eseguito l'accesso al controllo 'txtBoxProcessing' da un thread diverso da quello da cui è stata eseguita la creazione.

Comment: ok it was the textbox. tks it seems to work but now if i want a textbox to summarize the process where i have to code?

Comment: do it into the button click code before calling perform serialize,and also if this answer solves your problem then mark it as correct

Comment: tks but i need to understand multithread programming...:) bye

Comment: @MeJonata you may want to try this link  
 - > https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_multithreading.htm